# Passing arguments to Button functions

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a GUI using Tkinter. As it will get crowded I try to split it into multiple scripts.  How can I pass return values from one button function/command to another button which executes a whole different script but uses the return value of button1 for one of its functions?

So what I want is this. It is juts a rough sketch but I think one can understand what I am aiming for. I am open to different approaches.

**GUI.py**

```
import functions

arg1 = 1
button1 = tk.Button(...., command = lambda: functions.addOne(arg1))

button2 = tk.Button(**Run program executeTHIS.py with return value from button1 command**)
```

**functions.py**

```
addOne(arg1):
     value = arg1 + 1
     return value
```

**executeThis.py**

```
functionNeedingArgumentFromButton1(value):
     ...
     
     return something

...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to change `arg1` to `IntVar()`:

```py
import functions
from executeThis import functionNeedingArgumentFromButton1
...
arg1 = tk.IntVar(value=1)

button1 = tk.Button(..., command=lambda: functions.addOne(arg1))
button2 = tk.Button(..., command=lambda: functionNeedingArgumentFromButton1(arg1.get()))
...
```

###### functions.py

```py
...
def addOne(arg):
    arg.set(arg.get() + 1)
...
```

###### executeThis.py

```
...
def functionNeedingArgumentFromButton1(value):
   # do whatever you want on 'value'
   ...

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best would be to use wrapper functions for your Buttons. This seems not efficient for this case, but when you have complex operations this will keep your `GUI.py` readable. Here I use a `global variable` to share the value between Buttons and functions.

**GUI.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

from my_functions import addOne
from my_functions2 import functionNeedingArgumentFromButton1

value = 1

def wrapper1():
    global value
    value = addOne(value)
    var.set(value)


def wrapper2():
    global value
    value = functionNeedingArgumentFromButton1(value)
    var.set(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Import functions")

    Button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Run1", command=wrapper1)
    Button1.pack()

    Button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Run2", command=wrapper2)
    Button2.pack()

    var = tk.StringVar()
    var.set('0')

    label1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)
    label1.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

**my_functions.py**

```
def addOne(arg1):
    value = arg1 + 1
    return value
```

**my_functions2.py**

```
def functionNeedingArgumentFromButton1(value):
    value = value + 100
    return value
```